# Read the first word of each line of a text file into an ArrayList

Tags: java, file-io, arraylist, bufferedreader, fileinputstream

I have a long local text file and I would like to write a method that will read it and add the first word of each line into an `ArrayList` of `Strings`.

I have a very primitive understanding of basic I/O operations. Right now, from what I understand, I would need to have some kind of `InputReader` object read each first word and then use something like an `OutputStreamBuffer` to add each of those words as `Strings` to the `ArrayList` in turn. Am I on the right track?

If that is correct, I'm not exactly sure what the correct syntax would be to do it (especially with having the `InputStreamReader` go to the next line after copying the first word in each line. If I'm not even close, what would you guys do?

Thanks a lot for your help everyone. I hope my description was clear enough for you.

Comment: Take a look at the [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) documentation.  It's got most of what you want to do in there; from here, it's a matter of exploring which methods help you the most.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track - here's my general suggestion for your requirement...

1. Create an `ArrayList<String>` for storing your words
2. Use a `BufferedReader` to read from your file line-by-line using `readLine();`
3. Split the line up and read the first word only (maybe use the `String.split()` method or a `StringTokenizer` or a regex expression)
4. Store the word in the `ArrayList` using an `add()` method and then read the next line from point 2.

There shouldn't be a need to use an `OutputStream` for your `ArrayList`, thats just complicating things.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `java.util.Scanner`, specifically the hasNextLine and nextLine methods to get each line.

Then use another scanner on each line and the hasNext and next methods to get the first word, or use the String split method (or some other way) to get the first word.

Then add the first word into the `ArrayList<String>`.